# How to make redirects with HTTP Redirect smarter?

Tags: http, https, iis-8.5

What I mean by smarter is that they only work if the website's root is hit.

So `http://example.com` will redirect to `https://example.com`

but `http://example.com/Contact` won't redirect at all to https.

Is there a way to get the redirect to work even if I'm not requesting the home page of the site?

#### Details about my configuration:

I have 1 site set with HTTPS bindings and another site with HTTP bindings that redirects to the https url.

The HTTP site contains nothing but a Default.aspx and web.config file which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://loganyoung.co.za" childOnly="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The Default.aspx is basically blank.

The HTTP site binds to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\redir`

The HTTPS site binds to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\example.com\wwwroot`

#### PROBLEMS

1. When I add in the HTTP site set to redirect to the HTTPS site, the server never stops redirecting.

**NOTE:** I've not touched "Default Web Site" at all. I create an entirely new website for each one that I'm hosting.

Comment: This cannot be answered without details on your configuration.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I've updated the question to provide more info